# DP6 - No UI on application start

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have upgraded my Android of Things OS on my `RPi3` from `DP4` to `DP6` recently.   But since, when I launch my application from Android Studio, the `UI` does not display but I can still interact with it `button click event`.
I'm also using the official `RPi 7" Touchscreen Display` as my main screen.

Any idea where does the problem come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found where the problem was, it seems that `DP6` on `RPi3` with the `7" Official Touchscreen Display` do not display UI from app that are launched on a **portrait** screen orientation.